# How to find elements of an array in Python and add more information to it

Tags: python, regex, arrays, nltk

I used the nltk module to tag a sentence. But then, I need help to add more information to the tokens i.e.

- re-write NNP as noun and NN as non-noun (neglect others; VBD, IN,..)
- add 'CAPITALIZED' to words tagged NNP,
- add 'LOWERCASE' to words tagged NN

Here is an example

```
sentences = "John wrote His name as Ishmael"

def findPOS(input):
    tagged = nltk.sent_tokenize(input.strip())        
    tagged = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in tagged]        
    tagged = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in tagged ]         
    print tagged

findPOS(sentences)

>> [[('John', 'NNP'), ('wrote', 'VBD'), ('His', 'NNP'), ('name', 'NN'), ('as', 'IN'), ('Ishmael', 'NNP')]]

#extra information added and printed: 

(John CAPITALIZED noun)
(wrote non-noun)
(His CAPITALIZED noun)
(name LOWERCASE non-noun)
(as non-noun)
(Ishmael CAPITALIZED noun)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compactness (not recommended):

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> sent = "John write His name as Ishmael"
>>> [pos_tag(word_tokenize(i)) for i in sent_tokenize(sent)]
[[('John', 'NNP'), ('write', 'VBD'), ('His', 'NNP'), ('name', 'NN'), ('as', 'IN'), ('Ishmael', 'NNP')]]
>>> tagged_sent = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(i)) for i in sent_tokenize(sent)]
>>> [[(word,"CAPITALIZED" if word[0].isupper() else None, "noun" if word[1][0] == "N" else "non-noun") for word,pos in sentence] for sentence in tagged_sent]
[[('John', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun'), ('write', None, 'non-noun'), ('His', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun'), ('name', None, 'non-noun'), ('as', None, 'non-noun'), ('Ishmael', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun')]]
```

A more readable code:

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> sent = "John write His name as Ishmael"
>>> tagged_sents = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(i)) for i in sent_tokenize(sent)]
>>> added_annotation_sents = []
>>> for sentence in tagged_sents:
...     each_sent = []
...     for word, pos in sentence:
...             caps = "CAPITALIZED" if word[0].isupper() else None
...             isnoun = "noun" if word[1][0] == "N" else "non-noun"
...             each_sent.append((word,caps,isnoun))
...     added_annotation_sents.append(each_sent)
... 
>>> added_annotation_sents
[[('John', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun'), ('write', None, 'non-noun'), ('His', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun'), ('name', None, 'non-noun'), ('as', None, 'non-noun'), ('Ishmael', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun')]]
```

If you insist on deleting the `None` element if it word is not capitalized:

```
>>> [[tuple([ann for ann in word if ann is not None]) for word in sent] for sent in added_annotation_sents]
[[('John', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun'), ('write', 'non-noun'), ('His', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun'), ('name', 'non-noun'), ('as', 'non-noun'), ('Ishmael', 'CAPITALIZED', 'non-noun')]]
```